# Connect to wifi on boot up Ubuntu server 22.04

Tags: networking, server

I am trying to run ubuntu server in a headless raspberry pi. So I included some config file i.e the details of my network in `/etc/netplan/myconfig.yaml`, something like this:

```
network:   
  version: 2   
  renderer: networkd   
  ethernets:
    eth0:
      dhcp4: true
      optional: true   
  wifis:
    wlan0:
    dhcp4: true
    optional: true
    access-points:
      "My SSID":
        password: "My Password"
```

But this won't connect at startup, even though the files are correct YAML syntax.

I am aware that the reason could be that I am not running the netplan commands that set the file (i.e `sudo netplan configurate && sudo netplan apply`) I though this commands would run at start up anyways, but I guess I was wrong.

So, how do you recommend to do get the server to connect to wifi at startup?

I have seen too many tutorials that won't work, and I'd prefer someone with knowledge giving me some ideas, so I can properly understand how to do it.

Comment: The generic Linux method would be to create a systemd service Find a skeleton unit, add the command you use to connect from command line and enable the service :)

Comment: Ok, so I create a service that is enabled at startup and that simply runs my netplan commands? thanks a lot @Rinzwind

Comment: yeah ... it is not even as dauning as it reads No time on my end otherwise I'd make an answer now but I bet itn can be done in under 10 minutes.  Do add the actual command to the Q and if you do not manage I''ll make an answer if there is no yet

Comment: @Rinzwind only one question: I put the file under `/lib/systemd/system` but what is the Key to make sure it runs at startup? Is `ExecStart` enough?

Comment: @Rinzwind my try below. not working yet.

Comment: Hmmm looks like you should already have a unit called `systemd-networkd` that should read your netplan config. can you check if that one is active?  `systemctl status systemd-networkd`

Comment: The problem is that I don't have a way to check that, because my rpi is running headless (I don't have a monitor.) It is running Ubuntu Server 22.04 though.

Answer (score 0):

I configure Ubuntu 22.04 LTS Server headless successfully using Raspberry Pi Imager v1.7.3 and use the "gear" setup option to pre-configure the hostname, username/pswd, wifi SSID/pswd, locale, and SSH auth (I use password).

The imager will write a file /boot/network-config with the SSID and encrypted password you entered in the imager setup.

The first boot will configure everything - it takes some time before you can connect, and if you have previously remote ssh connected to that RPi, you will need to remove the existing ssh key in your desktop/laptop.  (on Mac: ssh-keygen -R X.X.X.X)

Sometimes your router will grant a different IP - funny stuff can happen so watch for a new IP in your network.

BTW, I always add ipv6.disable=1 to the end of the line in /boot/cmdline.txt because my RPi and Xfinity router combo will give an IPV6 address and I can't figure out how to connect, and sudo apt update sometimes fails for me with IPv6, and wget fails with a wierd https error (use wget -4 ... when that happens).

Sometimes, I have not been able to connect to the newly imaged system the first boot, but yanking the power when the green light is off, and rebooting sometimes - sometimes will connect the second time.

BUT Note: you only get one chance at setting the SSID/Password.  If for some reason you made a typo on the SSID or password such that the RPi does not successfully connect to your WiFi on that boot, you need to reflash the sdCard and set the options again.

This is my ["How To Setup Ubuntu 22.04 LTS Server headless"](https://github.com/slowrunner/ROS2-GoPiGo3/blob/main/Setup_1_Ubuntu22.04_LTS_Server.md)